# How can I set variables from a line of a CSV file that has other lines

Tags: variables, powershell, csv

I have found numerous way to do this for setting using all of CSV, either from export-csv or from a CSV file that has only what they need.  I have a pretty large file with multiple lines. Import-CSV with the proper heading parameter separates the each line into proper groupings, but I only need on line from the CSV file.

What I am trying to do is request input from user about a location number for any number of our locations. The CSV file starts each line with the location number, so I have used select-string to get only the line that I need but I'm not sure how to pipe that to import-csv to then use the header names to set variables to each header content.

If there is a better way to do this, please fill me in, but I am lost at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `Select-String` for this. If you're pre-filtering the text from the CSV use `Get-Content` in combination with a `Where-Object` filter. Then pipe the result into [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849890.aspx) and specify the headers via the `-Headers` parameter:

```
$locationId = 23

Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | ? { $_ -match "^$locationId" } |
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Headers 'LocationID', 'Foo', 'Bar', ...
```

Another option would be to use `Import-Csv` and filter on the particular field you want to process:

```
$locationId = 23

Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | ? { $_.LocationID -eq $locationId }
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to convert all the data values to separate values, but this works great in that I don't have to. I assume I can use this too with converting an array to CSV and then converting it back to manage somewhat of a table format. I've been searching how to do that too, as in get my own data, from variables and displaying it as a table; ie excel on powershell.

Comment: @user3377627 You could with some modifications. However, that's a different question and should be asked as such.